# String similarity with varying lengths but same words

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, similarity

I know there are many string similarity algorithms but I don't know which would be best for my problem.

My strings vary in length but usually have some extra fluff added to one or the other I want algorithm to give high similarity "points" when strings contain same words without typos. For example `Stuff and Things corp.` is same as `Stuff and Things corporation` or `101, Stuff and Things corporat` or `Stuff and Things`.

But strings `color` and `colour`, `Loremipsum` and `Olremipsum` in my case are totally different. My strings would never have characters which are mistyped or swapped also strings are 1 to 50 chars long.

EDIT:
Order of same words is very importat `New York city` would be different or have low level of similarity with `York New city`

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sounds like you want something like the count of identical words, possibly divided by the total word count.

Comment: Is `New York` equal to `New Delhi`?

Comment: No its not I know I can just simply compare identical words but I was hoping there already is algorithm little bit more sophisticated so I dont be reinventing wheel.

Comment: Maybe? http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/StrikeAMatch.html

Comment: @L.B: no, he doesn't want to find similar words(Soundex Algorithm, Edit Distance, and Longest Common Substring, Levenshtein,..).

Comment: I think there is another way to look at it. If words are together in right order it means high similarity. `New York city` and `York New city` are different strings so it also needs to take into account order of words.

Comment: @Hnus: what do you mean by _sophisticated_ and how would _you_ compare identical words? You haven't explained why New York and New Delhi are different. If the count of equal words compared to the total count of words is important you should mention that also.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would try to find biggest same part in other string with taking order of words/chars into account if that makes any sense. By sophisticated I mean that most of the algorithms use math I dont even understand and are written in the most efficient way possible and are tested many times. It certainly couldn't be said about algorithm I would come up with. As I said I don't want to reinvent wheel when there is *sophisticated* solution.

Comment: @Hnus: you should show more samples, it's still not clear what what you understand by "same part". Do you only compare words? What are word-separators? Do you want to find the greatest similar word sequence in two sentences? Or do you want to find it only if it has a minimum  similarity(f.e. 2/3 of total-words)? Provide strict rules and meaningful samples.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Im afraid I cant provide any more rules in my non native language. It would get even more clunky. If my description doesnt fit to any known algorithm already that tells me I need to write my own or try them all and see which suits me best. Thanks a lot for your imput

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, even if the rules still aren't that clear i'll give it a try.

To summary your requirement:

- Find the longest common word-sequence in another sentence
- At least two words must be common, so `New York` and `New Delhi` are not *equal*
- the order matters, so `New York city` and `York New city` are not equal

The method `FindCommonWords` returns a sequence of words that are common in both sentences or an empty sequence(`Enumerable.Empty<string>`) if no common word sequence was found.

It first splits both strings by a pre-defined list of word separators into two `string[]`. Then it checks all "sub-sequences" whether or not it is contained in the other array in the same order(with an extension method `IndexOfSequence`).

```
private static readonly char[] wordSeparators = { '\n', '\t', ',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', ' ', '-', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '(', ')', '<', '>', '@', '"', '\'' };

public static IEnumerable<string> FindCommonWords(string str1, string str2, StringComparer comparer = null)
{
    if (str1 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("str1", "Both input strings must not be null!");
    if (str2 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("str2", "Both input strings must not be null!");

    if (comparer == null) comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
    str1 = str1.Trim();
    str2 = str2.Trim();

    string[] words1 = str1.Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] words2 = str2.Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if(Math.Min(words1.Length, words2.Length) < 2)
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>(); // one word is not supposed to be a commnon word sequence

    // use for-loop to find the longest common words
    for (int wordCount = words1.Length - 1; wordCount >= 2; wordCount--)
    {
        // scan word-count from left to right
        for (int skipCount = 0; wordCount + skipCount <= words1.Length; skipCount++)
        {
            // take wordCount-words from left side and walk from left to right
            IEnumerable<string> wordSeq = words1.Skip(skipCount).Take(wordCount);
            // search sequence in other words
            int indexInWords2 = words2.IndexOfSequence(wordSeq, comparer);
            if (indexInWords2 >= 0)
            {
                // found match in other words, must be longest common sequence
                return wordSeq;
            }
        }
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Here's the extension which might also be useful for other requirements:

```
public static int IndexOfSequence<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (!sequence.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("Sequence must not be empty", "sequence");
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
    }
    int index = -1, firstIndex = -1, lastFoundIndex = -1;
    bool found = false;

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = input.GetEnumerator())
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator2 = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        {
            enumerator2.MoveNext();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                index++;
                found = comparer.Equals(enumerator.Current, enumerator2.Current);
                if (found && firstIndex == -1)
                    firstIndex = index;
                else if (found && index != lastFoundIndex + 1)
                    found = false; // sequence must be consecutive
                if (found && !enumerator2.MoveNext())
                    return firstIndex;
                if(found)
                    lastFoundIndex = index;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Here are your three samples:

```
var commonWords = FindCommonWords(
     "Stuff and Things corporation", 
     "101, Stuff and Things corporat", 
     StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", commonWords));   // Stuff and Things

commonWords = FindCommonWords(
     "101, Stuff and Things corporat",
     "or Stuff and Things.",
     StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(" ", commonWords) ); // Stuff and Things

commonWords = FindCommonWords(
     "New York city",
     "York New city",
     StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", commonWords));  // empty sequence, no match
```

Note that it's written from the scratch and not tested thoroughly.

Comment: That looks really great I even think it is exactly what I wanted. If I come up with new rules I can easily add them to your code its really great foundation for what Im trying to achieve. Thank you for your patience with me.